# Badass runtime plugin locale

Tags: java, javafx, locale, badass-runtime-plugin

I'm creating an image of my javafx application using Badass Runtime plugin https://github.com/beryx/badass-runtime-plugin
When I execute the bat file to launch my application the locale is not set to Spanish which is the locale of my code.
Any idea why is it happening and how can I solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: You'll probably get a quicker answer to this if you ask on the plugin's Github

Comment: I think, behind the scenes, badass uses jlink and/or jpackage.  To [include locales using jlink you need a special option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jlink.html). You also need the `jdk.localedata` module added. Example: `--add-modules jdk.localedata --include-locales=en,ja,*-IN`. I don’t know how you configure badass to pass the required option to jlink, perhaps it will be mentioned in the plugin documentation.